# Rally: How to Map test cases with user stories using REST API?

Tags: rally

I am writing code to create new test cases using rally restAPI.
Able to create the test cases under Test Plan & Test folder.
Now, want to map those test cases to Rally user stories.

Work product is the field to map it. But how to get the reference of user story using restAPI?

Please let me know if anyone has done in past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WS API user story is `HierarchicalRequirement` object. Query on the story, which you want to be a workproduct, and get its `_ref`. Then update the test case, e.g.

```
testCaseUpdate.addProperty("WorkProduct", storyRef);
```

Here is a Java example using [Rally Rest toolkit for Java](https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava), but the approach is the same regardless of your choice of language or toolkit:

```
public class UpdateTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


           String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
           String apiKey = "_abc123";
           String workspaceRef = "/workspace/123456";
           String applicationName = "RestExample_updateWorkProductOnTestCase";


           RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(host),apiKey);
           restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName);   

        try {
            String testid = "TC12";
            String storyid = "US34";

            QueryRequest testCaseRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCase");
            testCaseRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
            testCaseRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name", "WorkProduct"));
            testCaseRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=",  testid));
            QueryResponse testCaseQueryResponse = restApi.query(testCaseRequest);;

            if (testCaseQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount() == 0) {
             System.out.println("Cannot find test case : " + testid);
             return;
            }
            JsonObject testCaseJsonObject = testCaseQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            String testCaseRef = testCaseJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();
            System.out.println(testCaseRef);

            QueryRequest storyRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
            storyRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
            storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("FormattedID", "Name"));
            storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=",  storyid));
            QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);;

            if (storyQueryResponse.getTotalResultCount() == 0) {
             System.out.println("Cannot find test story : " + storyid);
             return;
            }
            JsonObject storyJsonObject = storyQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            String storyRef = storyJsonObject.get("_ref").getAsString();
            System.out.println(storyRef);

            JsonObject testCaseUpdate = new JsonObject();
            testCaseUpdate.addProperty("WorkProduct", storyRef);
            UpdateRequest updateTestCaseRequest = new UpdateRequest(testCaseRef,testCaseUpdate);
            UpdateResponse updateTestCaseResponse = restApi.update(updateTestCaseRequest);
            if (updateTestCaseResponse.wasSuccessful()) {
                System.out.println("Successfully updated : " + testid + " WorkProduct after update: " + testCaseUpdate.get("WorkProduct"));

            }

        } finally {
            restApi.close();
        }   
    } 
}
```